# Laravel validator, unique value when update info

Tags: php, laravel, validation

So i have validator that checks if reg_number is unique. I use it for creating new entries (that part works). However, when i try to update an existing one using another form - i get error that reg_number already exists (logical). So my question is how to edit the rule that it would make an exception when i try to update (update other fields and keep reg_number the same) and not create a new one. Found something in other forums (added at the end of the rule) but its not working. Code below:

```html
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'reg_number'=>'required|max:6|min:6|unique:cars'.$this->cars['reg_number'],
            'brand'=>'required',
            'model'=>'required'
         
          ];
    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example as to how to do this in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique).

Basically, you add the ID for the model instance you want to be excepted from this rule. E.g.:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'reg_number' => ['required', 'max:6', 'min:6', 'unique:cars,reg_number,' . $this->id],
        'brand'      => ['required'],
        'model'      => ['required'],
    ];
}
```